# Why does this session always return true?

Tags: php, session, if-statement, isset

I'm having trouble with my code.
Somehow an if-statement that checks sessions always returns true. Even at start. I can't really figure out why..

Here is my login page.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))   //<-----This always returns true here for a strange reason.
{
}   
?>
```

Here is my my login controller.

```
if($_POST)
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) AND $_POST['submit'] == "login")
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        try
        {
            include '../model/Login.php';
            $login = new Login($username, $password);

            if($login == TRUE)
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                header("Location:../index.php");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception $exc)
        {
            echo $exc->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION['username'])` to figure out what it contains. Then trace back to why it contains it.

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']))

Comment: @Manish `isset && !empty` is redundant nonsense, just use `!empty` if you have to use it at all.

Comment: If you are using `empty` then there is no need to use `isset`.

Comment: @deceze. It contains a username but how do I trace it back. The only trace I have is that it's coming from `if(isset($_SESSION['username']))`

Comment: "Trace it back" in the sense of *debug your own code*. We do not know how that value got there and we're not in a position to figure it out. Do some more `var_dump`ing here and there to confirm that your variable values are as you expect them at the right places, that your application works as you think it does. That'll inevitably lead to some place where your expectations and reality diverge, which is where your bug is.

Answer (score 1):

This is always returning true because even if $_SESSION['username'] is empty ( == ''), it is set.

To unset it, you can use :

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
```

or

```
session_destroy();
```

if you just want to test if it is empty, there is :

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){}//Will return false if $_SESSION['username'] == ''
```

or even

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != ''){}//Will return true if $_SESSION['username'] has a value (other than '')
```

PS : the advantage of empty() is that it will also test if the variable isset()

Comment: That does't explain why it's true at the beginning of the application when no interactions has been made. I already know about the session_destroy(). I'm just wondering why the session is set automatically at the start.

Comment: if you are in a local environment, you might have used the same $_SESSION variable in an other site. But if you are on a server, indeed, that's weird. Except if your server set a long session lifetime.